# No such module AVFoundation when testing on iPhone7.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, swift

I try to convert some code from Objective-C to Swift. In my controller I import AVFoundation framework. When testing in simulator everything works but when I try to compile it for my physical device with iOS 7.1.1 it says "No such module AVFoundation".

Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: did you managed to find the cause of this?

Answer (score -3):

You're not gonna like the answer, but I believe it's because Swift is only support on builds targeting iOS 8.0 /OSX 10.10 or later